# Create a list of sublists of a given list

Tags: list, haskell

I need a function that returns a list of all possible sublists, without skipping elements, e.g. sublists [1,2,3,4] should return [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3] etc.] but the list should NOT contain [1,2,4].
My current "solution" is

```
>sublists :: [Integer] -> [[Integer]]
>sublists [] = [[]]
>sublists (x:xs) = [x:ys | ys <- sublists xs] ++ sublists xs
```

which does include [1,2,4]

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Found a solution (with a little help of my friend)

Looks a bit clumsy but it works

```
>sublists :: [Integer] -> [[Integer]]
>sublists [] = [[]]
>sublists (x:xs) = subs [] (x:xs) ++ sublists xs
>    where
>        subs :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [[Integer]]
>        subs xs [] = [xs]
>        subs xs (a:as) =  (xs ++ [a]) : (subs (xs ++ [a]) as)
```

Comment: I want to implement it myself and it seems like tails for example would not return [1,2] when given [1,2,3]

Comment: If you didn't you want to implement it yourself as an exercise, you would be looking for [`inits`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:inits) from `Data.List`. (I miswrote `tails` instead of `inits` in my original comment.)

Comment: inits does not return [2,3] when given [1,2,3].

combining both skips [2,3] in [1,2,3,4]

Comment: `tails [1,2,3,4] >>= inits` is *almost* right; you just end up with too many empty lists in the output. Pass the result to `nub` and you're done (although that's probably not the most efficient solution).

Comment: I read your question as if getting `[2,3]` from `[1,2,3]` would count as skipping the first element. Perhaps a more precise way of stating your requirements would be "all possible sublists generated by removing prefixes and suffixes", or something to that effect.

Comment: The solution you added to the question is, in effect, an alternative answer. I suggest you post it as a separate answer (and not as a footnote to the question).

Comment: @duplode "All contiguous sublists".

Comment: @chepner, it's not even clear to me that there are too many empty lists in that solution.  There are four empty subsequences of `[1,2,3]`; the one at the beginning, the one between 1 and 2, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Data.List` contains both `inits` and `tails`. What you want is the inits of each member of the tails list (or possibly vice-versa, but see later for the reason why this way round is better)

```
sublists = concatMap inits . tails

> sublists [1,2,3,4]
[[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[],[2],[2,3],[2,3,4],[],[3],[3,4],[],[4],[]]
```

If you prefer, you might want to get rid of all the null lists:

```
sublists = filter (not . null) . concatMap inits . tails
```

Or if you prefer to avoid generating the null lists in the first place:

```
sublists = concatMap (tail . inits) . tails
```

The result of `inits` always starts with the empty list, while the result of `tails` always ends with the empty list. So `tail . inits` is safe because `tail` will never be applied to an empty list; it just returns the result without the leading empty list. `inits []` just returns `[[]]`, so the last empty list from `tails` gets dropped.